# Can I modify a Javascript library at runtime?

Tags: javascript

I use a web based development environment for data entry forms. The environment lets me create rules that are triggered by form events. These events run in js in the browser but there is almost no support for debugging, which makes problem solving a nightmare.

The code in the browser has a central event handler, which has a logging feature but the quantity of information produced by it is so large, it makes finding what you need difficult. Think of info level logging gone mad. Plus you have to open a separate window to access the log.

I need to be able to log certain events to the console, or trigger breakpoints at specified rules. Is there a way to modify the environment's code below to allow it to call my debugger instead of (or in addition) to SFLog?

```
function handleEvent(n,t,q,r,u,f,e,o,s,h,c,l){
    if(eventsCancelled!==!0){
        SFLog({type:3,source:"handleEvent",category:"Events",
            message:"{2} event fired from {1} - {0}",parameters:[n,t,q]});
            var b="Events/Event[@SourceID='"+n+"'][@SourceType='"+t+"'][Name/text()="+q.xpathValueEncode()+"]";
            //Rest of the event handler...

function SFLog(n){
    if(checkExists(_debug)){var s=translateDebugLevel(n.type);
    if(s>=_debug){
        varu=n.type,e=n.source,r=n.category,q=n.message,h=n.parameters,o=checkExists(n.exception)? WriteExceptionXml(n.exception):null,t=n.data,l=checkExists(n.humanateData)?
        n.humanateData:!0,f=(new Date).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fff");
        checkExists(t)&&(dataString=t.xml,checkExists(dataString)||(dataString=t),l===!0&&(dataString=Humanate(dataString)));               
        //more code for SFLog...
```

**Cleaned Up Code**

```js
function handleEvent(n, t, q, r, u, f, e, o, s, h, c, l) {
  if (eventsCancelled !== !0) {
    SFLog({
      type: 3,
      source: "handleEvent",
      category: "Events",
      message: "{2} event fired from {1} - {0}",
      parameters: [n, t, q]
    });
    var b = "Events/Event[@SourceID='" + n + "'][@SourceType='" + t + "'][Name/text()=" + q.xpathValueEncode() + "]";
    //Rest of the event handler...
  }
}

function SFLog(n) {
  if (checkExists(_debug)) {
    var s = translateDebugLevel(n.type);
    if (s >= _debug) 
    {
      varu = n.type;
      e = n.source;
      r = n.category;
      q = n.message;
      h = n.parameters;
      o = checkExists(n.exception) ? 
        WriteExceptionXml(n.exception) :  
        null;
      t = n.data;
      l = checkExists(n.humanateData) ?
        n.humanateData : 
        !0;
        
      f = (new Date).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fff");
      checkExists(t) && 
      (dataString = t.xml, checkExists(dataString) || 
      (dataString = t), l === !0 && (dataString = Humanate(dataString)));
      //more code for SFLog.
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the Google Chrome JS debugger with breakpoints?

Comment: That might be an option I can explore, but the js file for handleEvent is large and chrome takes up to 15 seconds to show the script and three seconds to move the cursor. Logging to the console would give me much greater control.

Comment: Generally when you have that many parameters, you might want to rethink the design. Maybe construct a class that holds all the parameters and pass that instead

Comment: The issue is it's not my class and the file is minified. I guess I'm asking, can I modify someone else's js in the browser? I've modified the title to reflect that thought.

Comment: Trying to understand. You want to modify either `handleEvent` or `SFLog` or both without modifying their original source files? Is that correct?

Comment: If it takes 15 seconds to load in Chrome, and 3 seconds to move the cursor, my guess would be that it's bloated and highly inefficient.

Comment: `or trigger breakpoints at specified rules.` In chrome you can use the reserved word `debugger;`, and this will automatically stop & pause the code for you.

Comment: These are minified source files coming from a library that is provided by the environment. Oh, I just realized I have access to those files. Maybe I can modify them?!!

Comment: Can you enable sourcemaps for debugging?

Comment: Sourcemaps. that sounds like an excellent idea. I just tried adding a console.log to the source code and it locked up but it's worth pursuing modifying the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [@Eddie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6667219/eddie-del-rio) but one solution could be to wrap the logger function and and override it, and only log the events you care about. e.g.:

```
function SFLog(n){
  //old code
}
//run on the console, the first line, and then the second.
var oldLoggger = SFLog;
function SFLog(n) {
  if(/*some criteria*/) {
    oldLogger(n);
  }
}
```

This way you can run the default logger with different conditions, but it probably would be best if you could modify the logger code itself to accept certain criteria, like, event type to log, or targetElement's ID, class etc.

PD: If you need to modify the eventHandler itself, you should:

1. remove the event handler first.
2. create your wrapper function.
3. add the wrapper function as event handler

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was thinking. Modify the logger to filter events as I need. I just didn't know quite how to override the existing function with my own. I was also able to modify the source files on the server but this is better as I don't touch the original.